# How can locked posts be editable?

Tags: discussion, edits, locked-questions

The locked post FAQ says locked posts cannot be edited, yet [Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript/2366237#2366237) can be edited (at least, the lock message says so, and I can open the edit dialogue).

Comment: @AndrewT. The top answer.

Comment: Sorry for the possible dupe, it seems you have read it before posting here. However, the answer also says "*In the case of locked questions, the (unlocked) answers are not bounded to these (e.g. edit, voting) restrictions.*"

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah yes, so answers and questions can be separately locked? The reason I ask is that on AU we're discussing what to do with old off topic questions (like lists and polls). If the answers can be left editable, locking might be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *question* is locked. And you can't edit it.

The *answers* are not locked. And you *can* edit those.

Comment: Is that true of all locked posts? I think one can't vote on answers of locked posts as well, but edits are allowed?

Comment: There's *one* lock type that'll lock all answers as well as the question: the "Historical Lock". It's special in a few other ways also. All other locks just lock the post they're applied to and, for questions, prevent *new* answers from being added.